# How to send cell by cell data from a excel (xslx) file by using single hotkey every time?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to send data from a excel file to some another file by using Loop (read file contents) command in autohotkey. But it is not working. As I made a script which is as follows:

```
FileRead, fileData, D:\data.xlsx
lineIndex := 1

f1::
    Loop, Parse, fileData, `n
    {

        if (A_Index == lineIndex) {
            SendInput, %A_LoopField%

            lineIndex++
            break
        }
    }
return
```

In the above example I made <kbd>F1</kbd> a hotkey. There is a data.xlsx file in my D drive. Now I want that when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> key it should send the data (value) of one cell only at a time from `data.xlsx` file.

When I again press <kbd>F1</kbd> key it should send the data of next cell from `data.xlsx` file and so on. But it is not doing so. However, it is working perfectly with .txt files i.e. it is sending data line by line from any `.txt` file but this is not working at all with `.xlsx` files.

Answer (score 1):

FileRead doesn't work with `.xlsx` files as they have a special format. You need to export your data to a `.csv` file and parse that if possible.

Comment: One of the issues is the use of the HEX 00 values in many formatted files. This HEX 00 is interpreted as a End Of File by AHK. There are ways around it, but if you can use .CSV that would be much easier.